# Is jQuery needed for jQuery mobile in phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am a beginner in developing phonegap Android applications. I just to ask is it necessary to include jQuery to make jQuery mobile work means is jQuery mobile dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is built using jQuery. It wont work without adding reference to jQuery in your HTML file. See this sample from jQuery Mobile website: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html